# How to find "fat" procedure memory usage?

Tags: delphi, memory-management

While working on my code lately, I've noticed that some of the memory usage is going up significantly, and I can't see many reasons for it in my code.  So I'm wondering if there are any programs, techniques, or other types of tools that can scan my code (Delphi) and estimate for me what procedures, functions, and functions will be the heaviest memory users.  Ideally, I' think I'd be looking at the code as it is run in debug mode, but if something can scan the source files and tell me, that would be even better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of tool you are looking for is a Profiler.  There are lots of good profilers out there for most languages.  I'm less familiar with Delphi though so I used google and it turned the following options

- http://www.prodelphi.de/
- http://delphitools.info/

But the best information seems to be on this question from StackOverflow

- [Delphi Profiling tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368938/delphi-profiling-tools)

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to a similar question:

[Memory profiling tool for Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579909/memory-profiling-tool-for-delphi)

Without knowing how you are currently measuring "memory use" it's difficult to say what might be the best tools to use.

Comment: the problem is, we're not at this time.  Out application is built to be as dynamic as possible, which is why i want to start this process.  And of course, I'm junior enough in the field to not know about profilers, but I'm also the most senior developer we have at my office.

Answer (score 1):

We have used AQTime in the past it found a load of memory leaks. 
http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/

another good Delphi tool is Eurekalog